# Adding a translatable language in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add a line of text for a link leading to an external gallery, of course, translatable. How do I proceed? I added this line:

```
{l s='Gallery' mod="blocktopmenu"}
```

However, when I go in admin to translate it, that line doesn't exist. How to I make it exist in the translation section?

Comment: If you added that line to `blocktopmenu.tpl` then your code is ok. Did you look for the string in `Installed module translations`?

Comment: Yes, it is not appearing there. So there must be 1 step that is not documented. I also tried loading the page in both languages and it only shows the default text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the single quotes with double quotes:

```
{l s="Gallery" mod="blocktopmenu"}
```

Comment: That was almost it, thanks for the idea! It has to be double quotes though.

Comment: @MrJack I edited my answer though it was working for me with single quotes only.

Comment: I suspect it is probably a version or module issue. First time I ever see quotes actually matter though, don’t know how those programmers think but its really weird up to now.